# How to combine multiple column

Tags: ms-access

I wanted to combine 11 columns of a form into single column.
here is my query

```
SELECT DormData.BuildingID, 
    BuildingDetails.BuildingName, 
    Contractors.Item, 
    ActionDetails.ActionType,
    (DormData.Note1 
        + DormData.Note2 
        + DormData.Note3 
        + DormData.Note4 
        + DormData.Note5
        + DormData.Note6
        + DormData.Note7
        + DormData.Note8
        + DormData.Note9
        + DormData.Note10
        + DormData.Note11) AS Notes
FROM ActionDetails 
    INNER JOIN (Contractors 
        INNER JOIN (BuildingDetails 
            INNER JOIN DormData 
                ON BuildingDetails.BuildingID = DormData.BuildingID) 
            ON Contractors.ID = DormData.ItemID) 
        ON ActionDetails.ActionID = DormData.ActionID;
```

But not getting required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the + with a &

Comment: I see you are new to Stack Overflow. You should accept my answer if it solves your problem. That helps build my reputation on the site.

Comment: also plz give me your email id so that i can directly interact with u for any assistance . i am a open person

Comment: Just click on the check mark to the left of the answer. It will turn green to indicate that you accepted the answer. Sorry, I do not want to share my email. Best bet is to post new questions here as you have them.

Comment: The & concatenation operator ignores Nulls, while the + concatenation operator propagates them (`"String" & Null` returns `"String"`, while `"String" + Null` returns `Null`).